# CSS height 100% not working on TD

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why height 100% for css link is not inheriting height value pointed at td or table? But width value with 100% inherits value of the td or table.

```css
.mybutton a { 
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #666666;
color: #FFFFFF
}

.mybutton a:hover { 
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #666666;
color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210" height="50">
<tr>
<td width="210" height="50" class="mybutton"><p align="center"><a href="#">BUTTON</a></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Set the height on the `p` element, because `a` is getting the 100% from it.

Comment: @Troyer thanks bro, it is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height:inherit` for `p` tag element.

Comment: @Oleg if its working, then you mark this solution as **Answer** and close it.

Comment: @Deepak Yadav I can't accept the answer, this option has a delaying time for 10 minutes. Waiting for it... %)